# Making a grouped WPF ItemsControl accessible to screen readers

Tags: .net, wpf, accessibility, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` in my WPF application. This application must be accessible to screen reader software such as Narrator, NVDA and JAWS.

The problem is that when using grouping, child items within that `ItemsControl` suddenly become invisible to screen readers. If I remove the grouping, they appear.

How can I have grouping and visibility of items to screen readers?

Answer (score 3):

WPF UI elements can expose "automation peers" to screen readers.

By default, WPF does not ship a peer for `ItemsControl`, though it does for derived controls such as `ListBox`.

To get around this you can create your own derived control and have it return an automation peer.

```cs
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public sealed class AccessibleItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new AccessibleItemsControlAutomationPeer(this);
    }

    private sealed class AccessibleItemsControlAutomationPeer : ItemsControlAutomationPeer
    {
        public AccessibleItemsControlAutomationPeer(ItemsControl owner)
            : base(owner)
        {
        }

        protected override ItemAutomationPeer CreateItemAutomationPeer(object item)
        {
            return new AccessibleItemAutomationPeer(item, this);
        }

        protected override string GetClassNameCore() => "AccessibleItemsControl";

        protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore() => AutomationControlType.List;
    }

    private sealed class AccessibleItemAutomationPeer : ItemAutomationPeer
    {
        public AccessibleItemAutomationPeer(object item, ItemsControlAutomationPeer itemsControlAutomationPeer)
            : base(item, itemsControlAutomationPeer)
        {
        }

        protected override string GetClassNameCore() => "AccessibleItemsControlItem";

        protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore() => AutomationControlType.DataItem;
    }
}
```

You can specify the automation name of items and groups in XAML with code like this:

```xml
<controls:AccessibleItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <!-- customise the binding path here to suit your application -->
      <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Path=MyDisplayName}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style>
          <!-- customise the binding path here to suit your application -->
          <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Path=(CollectionViewGroup.Name).MyDisplayName}" />
        </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
</controls:AccessibleItemsControl>
```